# Setting Backbone attributes in a model in a nested collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Pretty new to Backbone JS and I need to know the 'right' way of looping through and setting attributes on models in a collection that is within a model.

My models look like this:

```
var mediaItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var mediaItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: mediaItem
});

var story = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.MediaItems = new mediaItems(this.get('MediaItems'));
        this.MediaItems.parent = this;
    }
});
```

What I want to do is loop through the MediaItems in a given story and set the width and height of each.  If I do it like this...

```
storyInstance.MediaItems.each(function (mediaItem) {
                            mediaItem.set('Width', 200);
                            mediaItem.set('Height', 100);
                    });
```

...then the MediaItem models within the storyInstance.MediaItems property are correctly updated, but the objects within storyInstance.attributes.MediaItems are not.  And it's the attributes tree that appears to be used when I subsequently call toJSON() on the Story model.

I can probably amend the above to loop through attributes instead, but I get the feeling I've set up the models wrong or there's a more standard way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, something else is wrong -- calling `set` should update the attributes.  What are you referring to here: "the models within the MediaItems property"?  I don't see that part in the code.

Comment: I've just added a couple of comments to Ravi Hamsa's answer below - hopefully that helps to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Probably initialize something other than what you expected.

The below code

```
var story = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.MediaItems = new mediaItems(this.get('MediaItems'));
        this.MediaItems.parent = this;
    }
});
```

should have been

```
var story = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.MediaItems = this.get('MediaItems');
        this.MediaItems.parent = this;
    }
});
```

and instantiating items should be done with instantiation of story model like

```
var storyInstance = new story({
    MediaItems: new mediaItems()
})
```

then

```
story.MediaItems.each(function (mediaItem) {
                        mediaItem.set('Width', 200);
                        mediaItem.set('Height', 100);
                });
```

would result updating both

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm using fetch to populate the Story model and if I use your code above, then storyInstance.Mediaitems becomes an array of MediaItem models, rather than a MediaItems collection, which means I can't use each to iterate through it.

Comment: If I stick with "new mediaItems(this.get('MediaItems'))" then MediaItems is set as a Collection and I can use each, but if I 'set' the width/height then the models within story.MediaItems are updated correctly, but the objects within story.attributes.MediaItems are not updated - and its these objects that appear to be used when I run story.getJSON.

Comment: Did you try using this code? when I set an attribute I am setting a collection, when as store that as this.MediaItems the same will get passed by reference, there is no conversion to array here.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Did not realize this was from '13. It showed up in questions tagged backbone.js and I did not notice the date/time till now.

Try to check for the instance of Array in the initialize section.

```
var story = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        if(this.get('MediaItems') instanceof Array){
            this.MediaItems = new mediaItems(this.get('MediaItems'));
        }
        else {
            this.MediaItems = this.get('MediaItems');
        }

        this.MediaItems.parent = this;
    }
});
```